# How to change background color with out !important when using primeng turbo table

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I want to change background color of row in a table,i followed the [turtorial](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/style) with [ngclass] and !important mark.

Here is the template.

```
<ng-template pTemplate = "body" let-hazard let-columns = "columns" >
<tr [pSelectableRow] = "hazard" [ngClass] = "getRiskLevelClass(hazard)" >
  <td *ngFor = "let col of columns" >
    {{col.field=="riskLevel"?getRiskLevel(hazard[col.field]):hazard[col.field]}}
  </td >
</tr >
</ng-template >
```

The function get css class.

```
  getRiskLevelClass ( hazard : Hazard ) {
  switch ( Number.parseInt ( hazard.riskLevel ) ) {
  case 1 :
    return "level1";
  case 2 :
    return "level2";
  case 3 :
    return "level3";
  case 4 :
    return "level4";
  default:
    break;
}
}
```

The css class.

```
.level1{
 background-color: blue !important;
   color: white !important;
 }
 .level2{
   background-color: yellow !important;
   color: black !important;
 }
 .level3{
   background-color: orange !important;
   color: white !important;
 }
 .level4{
   background-color: red !important;
   color: white !important;
 }
```

But when i selected a row. the style didn't change the way it did in plain p-table.
Is there a way to both changing barkground color and reserve the effect of select in p-table?

Comment: Adding a code snippet usually helps as we can get to the issue faster (without having to go through a tutorial, for example)

Comment: Thank you, i have add my code fragment.

Comment: Did you find the solution? If so, please post it.